# Example of relation that is neither transitive nor intransitive?

Tags: logic, relations

I have been struggling to think of an example of a relation that is neither transitive nor intransitive, does anyone have any tips? I ended up finding [one website that described this as non transitive](http://logic.philosophy.ox.ac.uk/tutorial8/Tut8-04.htm), but they're description just confused me even more.

The website defines:

> $Rxy$ is intransitive just if there is no broken journey in its graph with a short cut. That is: $Rxy$ is intransitive just if
>   $$\forall x\forall y \forall z\ [[Rxy \wedge Ryz] \implies \neg Rxz]$$

Comment: If "intransitive" means "not transitive," then you obviously cannot find such a relation. So what is your definition of "intransitive?"

Comment: If there is no broken journey in a graph with a shortcut

Comment: I edited in the relevant definition, so that the readers don't have to go to another website to look for it there.

Comment: I assumed whoever would know the answer to my question would know the meaning of transitive and intransitive. The website was there for the description of non-transitive because non-transitive is not the precise word for what i'm looking for as some documentation calls intransitive non-transitive. Thanks anyway though ;)

Answer (score 2):

Let $S$ be the set of all countries on Earth and consider the "is a neighbour of" relation on $S$.

Notice that this relation is not transitive. To see this, observe that Canada is a neighbour of USA and USA is a neighbour of Mexico, but Canada is not a neighbour of Mexico.

Furthermore, notice that this relation is not intransitive. To see this, observe that Norway is a neighbour of Sweden and Sweden is a neighbour of Finland, but Norway is a neighbour of Finland.

Comment: I believe that relationship is neither transitive nor *anti-transitive*.

Comment: @A.E I agree that anti-transitivity is a better term to use. Unfortunately, some people like referring to this property as intransitivity instead (including the author of the page linked to by the OP).

Comment: Indeed, I jumped the gun and did not visit the page. Darn philosophers :)